# Can't Create ActiveX Control

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

Working on getting a legacy app up and running again for work. I'm getting an error at run time that I can't create an activeX control. The suspect call is

```
oSQL = CreateObject("SQLDMO.SQLServer2")
```

I did a bit of googling and found that SQLDMO should be in a SQLDMO.dll. I've got that DLL referenced in my project but it is still failing. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Sorry should have said the error is the title. The only error I get is Can't Create ActiveX Control. I can provide a stack dump to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling createobject bypasses your project references, so you have a choice, you can try to create the instance with the 'new' operator, or continue using create object.

I'd advise against CreateObject.
Create object will look up that libraryName.objectName from the registry, debugging problems there is difficult.

Ps the dll must be registered with regsvr32

Pps beware 64bit processes calling 32bit dlls, they will always fail